# Multiplicative group of a ring as a morphism of theories

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic

[On nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrine#as_2monads) I read

> For instance, there is a morphism of theories from the theory of commutative rings to the theory of abelian groups which sends a ring to its multiplicative group of units, but this is not induced by any morphism of monads because it does not preserve the underlying set.

Can anyone tell me: what theories and what morphisms are we talking about? From the point of view of Lawvere single-sorted theories, there is no such morphism either, because the functors induced by them also preserve the underlying set (actually, the category of Lawvere theories is equivalent to the category of finitary monads on $\mathrm{Set}$).

Probably, we are talking about theories with some more powerful logic? (like geometric?)

Comment: A morphism of theories is a product preserving functor, and $(R\times S)^\times =R^\times\times S^\times$.

Comment: No need to go to geometric. This phenomenon can already be seen at the level of cartesian (= finite limit) theories.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I don't quite understand what you mean: we need a functor between theories (preserving the product, yes), not between categories of algebras.

Comment: @ArshakAivazian you said the theory of commutative rings not the theory whose algebras are commutative rings.

Comment: @FernandoMuro But what theories do you mean? If we talk about algebraic theories (= Lawvere theories), then there is no morphism that induces the desired functor, do you agree?

Comment: @ZhenLin Really! After dualization, the group ring functor $\mathbb{Z}[-]^{\mathrm{op}} \colon \mathrm{Group}_{\mathrm{fin}}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Ring}_{\mathrm{fin}}^{\mathrm{op}}$ preserves finite limits (initially it is left adjoint, hence after dualization it preserves all limits). And the functor induced by it on the categories of algebras sends the ring $R$ to the group whose presheaf $G \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[G], R) = \mathrm{Hom}(G, R^{\times})$. So this is the group of invertible elements $R$. Thank you! If you post this answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Generally "the theory of X" means "the theory whose algebras are X".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functor sending a (not necessarily commutative) ring to its group of units is induced by a morphism of *cartesian* (= finite limit) theories.

More generally, suppose given (small!) cartesian theories $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$.
Let $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}'$ be the respective categories of models.
These are locally finitely presentable categories, so given a functor $G : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}'$; the following are equivalent:

- $G$ preserves (small) limits and filtered colimits.
- $G$ has a left adjoint that sends finitely presentable objects in $\mathcal{M}'$ to finitely presentable objects in $\mathcal{M}$.

But $\mathcal{T}^\textrm{op}$ (resp. $\mathcal{T}'{}^\textrm{op}$) is equivalent to the full subcategory of finitely presentable objects in $\mathcal{M}$ (resp. $\mathcal{M}'$), so we deduce the following is also equivalent:

- $G$ is induced by a morphism $\Phi : \mathcal{T}' \to \mathcal{T}$ of cartesian theories, in the sense that $G \cong \Phi^*$, where $\Phi^* (M) = M \Phi$.

(Note the contravariance!)